# Regex to get Complete Name in C

Tags: c, regex

I need to get a client name from Java's log using a `C regex`.

I have tested this regex `Client:\\s[a-zA-Z\\s]+` [here](http://regexr.com/62d53) and works fine.

But in my `C` program, dont.

```c
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  regex_t preg;

  const char *string =
      "[com.example.app.JavaClass.JavaMethod(JavaClass.java:1)] (Thread-1) - "
      "Client: FirstName MiddleName AnotherName LastName, Wallet: WL01, "
      "Agency: 9999, ID: 06611486123, Ticket: TKR211";
  const char *pattern = "Client:\\s[a-zA-Z\\s]+";

  size_t nmatch = 1;
  regmatch_t pmatch[1];

  regcomp(&preg, pattern, REG_ICASE | REG_EXTENDED);

  int ret = regexec(&preg, string, nmatch, pmatch, 0);

  char *match = calloc(pmatch[0].rm_eo - pmatch[0].rm_so, sizeof(char));
  memcpy(match, &string[pmatch[0].rm_so], pmatch[0].rm_eo - pmatch[0].rm_so);

  printf("ret: %d\n", ret);
  printf("rm_eo0: %d\n", pmatch[0].rm_eo);
  printf("rm_so0: %d\n", pmatch[0].rm_so);

  printf("Match: %s\n", match);

  regfree(&preg);

  return 0;
}
```

`$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings reg.c && ./a.out`

When I execute this I get this output:

```
ret: 0
rm_eo0: 87
rm_so0: 70
Match: Client: FirstName
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Beware: lots of people's names have characters that aren't `[a-zA-Z\s]` (e.g. `'`, `-`)

Comment: I simplified the use case, but in this moment my interest is to get the complete name.

Comment: @Alexander Æ A-12 Musk :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace `\s` inside the bracket expression with `[:space:]` POSIX character class:

```c
const char *pattern = "Client:\\s[a-zA-Z[:space:]]+";
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/vDtqrG).

The reason for this behavior is that POSIX regex flavor does not allow shorthand character classes like `\s`, `\w`, etc. inside bracket expressions, the `[\s]` pattern matches a backslash or `s` char in [POSIX ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (enabled with the `REG_EXTENDED` flag). POSIX character classes are meant to be used inside bracket expressions and they make up for this shortcoming.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why the `\\s` doesnt work in this case?

Comment: @WiltonRodrigues The first `\s` works fine since it is an extension to the POSIX flavor implemented in `regex.h`. The second one is forbidden by POSIX standard, `[\s]` pattern is described in the answer.

Comment: Should use `[[:space:]]` instead of the first `\s`, too. Not all implementations of EREs understand the latter.

Comment: @Shawn This one does. GNU POSIX utilities like `sed` and `grep` also support `\s`.